# Qt C++ - QList<float**> type not allowed

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, list, types

I would like to pass a list of `float**` arguments to some method which is working with C-syle and `float**` only (but we consider we can have a `QList<>` as arguments type).

I tried with

```
QList< float** > list_ = new QList< float** >();
```

but this is not working. What should i use instead ? What would be for instead Qt container for a list of 2D matrices ?

thanks

Comment: Why is this "not working"? Do you get an error? Which one?

Comment: That's because you are using the `new` operator which will allocate it on the heap and return a pointer. You do not need to do anything after that equals sign.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using a java like syntax (or c# or others)

In C++ it should be either

```
QList<float**> *list_ = new QList<float**>() ;   //Pointer to a heap allocated list, Closer to what you wanted to do i think. NEED TO CALL "delete list_" once you are done with it.
```

or

```
QList<float**> list_; //List on the stack, more c++ish, destroyed once it goes out of scope.
```

Comment: Creating Qt containers on the heap is almost always nonsensical though, due to implicit sharing.